# How do i add multithreading to this server side in socket programming ,i am new to socket programming I've been trying a lot to add multithreading

Tags: python, websocket, network-programming, client-server, serversocket

```
#import socket module 
from http import server

from socket import * 
import sys # In order to terminate the program 
import threading

def webServer(serverport=5501):
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #Prepare a server socket 
    
    #Fill in start
    serverSocket.bind(('',serverport))
    serverSocket.listen(1) 
    print('The Web server is up on Port:',serverport)
    #Fill in end 
    while True: 
        #Establish the connection 
        print('Ready to serve...') 
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()#Fill in start 
        #Fill in end 
        try: 
            message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)#Fill in start 
            filename=message.split()[1]
            #Fill in end 
            f = open(filename[1:]) 
            outputdata =f.read() #Fill in start
            
            #Fill in end 
            #Send one HTTP header line into socket 
            #Fill in start 
            connectionSocket.send(bytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n","UTF-8"))
            print(outputdata)
            #Fill in end 
            #Send the content of the requested file to the client 
            for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
                connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode()) 
            connectionSocket.close() 
        except IOError: 
            #Send response message for file not found 
            #Fill in start
            connectionSocket.send(bytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n","UTF-8"))
            connectionSocket.send(bytes("<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html>\r\n","UTF-8"))
            #Fill in end 
            #Close client socket 
            #Fill in start
            connectionSocket.close() 
            #Fill in end 
    serverSocket.close()   
    sys.exit()#Terminate the program after sending the corresponding data 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        webServer(6789)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: `How do i add multithreading to ...` - Read through the [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [AsyncIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), [ConcurrentFutures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) docs. Study the examples, get a feel for what might work for you; try to implement something.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the tim to read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of how to do this.